# How to color each character differently in a TableView TableCell

Tags: scalafx

I have a tableview and in one column I would like to be able to **indvidually color each character** of the string. Apparently, textFill only works on the entire cell, as I did try splitting the string by characters first.  I've included the code below which *does not quite* do as I wish, but is indicative (it changes the cell text color based only upon the first character).   How can I adjust to get a multicolored output in that cell? [note: the unicode characters are up and down arrows]

```
    val colTick = new TableColumn[Quote, String] {
      editable = false
      text = "Tick"
      prefWidth = 90
      alignmentInParent = scalafx.geometry.Pos.Center
      cellFactory = { _ =>
        new TableCell[Quote, String] {
          item.onChange { (_, _oldTick, newTick) =>
            if (newTick == null) {
              text = null
              graphic = null
            } else {
              if (newTick(0) == '\u2B06') {
                textFill = Color.Green
              } else {
                if (newTick(0) == '\u2B07') textFill = Color.Red else textFill = Color.Black
              }
              text = newTick
            }
          }
        }
      }
      cellValueFactory = {
        _.value.tick
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from remarks given by @Jarek, this code seems to work now:

```
      cellFactory = { _ =>
        new TableCell[Quote, String] {
          item.onChange { (_, _oldTick, newTick) =>
            if (newTick == null) {
              text = null
              graphic = null
            } else {
              val texts = newTick.map { c =>
                val color: Color = c match {
                  case '⬇' => Color.Red
                  case '⬆' => Color.Green
                  case '_' => Color.Crimson
                  case '￮' => Color.DarkBlue
                  case _ =>Color.Black
                }
                new Text {
                  setText(c.toString)
                  setFill(color)
                }

              }
              graphic = new javafx.scene.layout.HBox(texts: _*)
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use separate `Text` for each character, so you can set its color individually. Then combine those `Text`s in `HBox`, `TextFlow` or whatever is suitable. Here is an example where characters `r`, `g`, and `b` will be in color, other characters in black:

```scala
cellFactory = { _ =>
  new javafx.scene.control.TableCell[Quote, String] {
    override def updateItem(item: String, empty: Boolean): Unit = {
      super.updateItem(item, empty)
      setText(null)
      if (item == null || empty) {
        setGraphic(null)
      } else {
        val texts = item.map { c =>
          val color: Color = c.toLower match {
            case 'r' => Color.Red
            case 'g' => Color.Green
            case 'b' => Color.Blue
            case _ => Color.Black
          }
          new Text {
            text = c.toString
            fill = color
          }
        }
        setGraphic(new HBox(texts: _*))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the proper direction.  However, the override was being rejected.  The key things though were the Text type and the Hbox.  I've posted the working fragment for comparison.